# SQL Server scalar function with table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a user defined function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getMinutesWork
(
    @startT datetime,
    @endT datetime
)
RETURNS int
As
Begin
    bla bla
    bla bla
RETURN @totalMinute
End
```

It calculates total minutes between two dates. I want to use it with a table like this:

```
WorkerID |LastName| FirstName  |  StartDate          | EndDate
   1     |   JOHN |    SNOW    |1979-12-26 02:47:00  | 1999-02-16 12:44:00
   2     |  ...   |   ...      |   .... .            |    .....
```

`StartDate` and `EndDate` are inputs. But i couldnt figure out how ill turn my function `table valued` one

Comment: I'm not following... what is your question?  Are you wanting to know how to pass in the values from your table?

Comment: @siyual Yes. I want to use this function for 3-5k people and see each total minutes  on a table.

Comment: I think you are confusing a table valued function, with calling a scalar function using values from a table. As far as I can tell your query would be ---- `SELECT t.WorkerID, t.LastName, t.Firstname, t.StartDate, t.EndDate, MinutesWork = getMinutesWork(t.StartDate, t.EndDate) FROM YourTable AS t`

Comment: Performance wise you would be better off if you can use a inline table valued function instead of a scalar function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call your function in the `select`:

```
select t.*,
       dbo.getMinutesWork(StartDate, EndDate)
from table t;
```